# Script to Log into several user accounts

Tags: windows, automation

We manage several laptops that are used for emergency situations and thus are rarely used (knock on wood).

When we start up these laptops periodically to run windows updates, we also sign in with several user accounts for each laptop in order to keep the profile up to date.

Is there a way to automate the logging in of each account with a script?

For example, I could log in as administrator, run the script and the laptop would do the following:

Log out my administrator account,

sign in with useraccount 1, log out

sign in with useraccount 2, log out

sign in with useraccount 3, log out

I havent had much luck in googling this type of thing and was hoping someone here might have an idea.

I simply cant find a script that logs in with a user account.
The closest I can find is recommending auto signin but that only applies to one account and not what I need for this task.

Answer (score 0):

Globally, you can't do that: it would break security if you were allowed to interact, programmatically, with the login screen.

**IF** it's possible, I would look to a way to do the login to remote machine through either Telnet (not recommended! but can be done with standard Windows tools) or SSH (will need a SSH server). If you can do the upgrade this way, then you're saved, in particular with SSH because you can avoid passwords' sharing through key exchange - probably won't work with domain accounts, however, but local accounts will be fine.

Otherwise, if you require to really open a Windows session, best you can do, **IF** your configuration allows it **AND** if it works (regarding the profile's update) is to connect through RDP (Remote Desktop) to each laptop, with each login.

You'll need to establish a RDP connection to each laptop from a "pilot" PC, save each connexion individually within a `.rdp` file, saving password inside the connection file.

Then, you can launch the connection with the command `mstsc <machine+account>.rdp` to establish a connection. A bit later, you can kill the connection (with either `taskkill` or through a pilot process / tool, I would use [AutoIt](https://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/) for this preferably).

If password saving is an issue, then each employee should have its own set of RDP files. Through something like Autoit, in particular, you can input the password once, and fill automatically each password prompt.

The tricky part would be to know when it's time to close the remote desktop. I would try to automatically execute a command to distant computer that would reboot it once done, so your remote desktop would close automatically.

Anyway, it will be a real gas plant to implement all this in a smooth process...